# Web Browser inside blogspot? (Browser inside a browser)

Tags: browser, html, blogspot

I was curious if I can place a web broswer (most basic one) inside a blog post(in a webpage)? 
To clarify: 
webpage that has a browser lead to another webpage, sub browser in a sense.

Please save all the silly comments and/or jokes. I'm just curious

Comment: If the post allows you to add iframe then you are done...Browser inside browser....:)

Comment: I know of something called [Bitty Browser](http://www.bitty.com/) that can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably searching for is to use iframe tags. A quick search shows a few tutorials that should help you.

http://www.ehow.com/how_12109858_add-iframe-code-blogspot.html

http://www.bloggerhacking.com/2010/04/iframe-to-add-another-blog-into-your.html

Also more details on iframes

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Be warned it wont do wonders for your SEO